# Is it safe to use Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My understanding is that Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE and Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE events were added after the initial release of Flash Player 9, but I simply cannot find information on whether this has any lasting repercussions today.  Compatibility is very important to me and I'm willing to go out of my way to ensure it if need be, I just need to know if it's necessary.

So, does anybody actually still try to play flash games with original Flash Player 9, or can I safely use these events?

Comment: Read this great article about it http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/12/03/understand-added_to_stage-event/, when new DisplayObject is added to the stage using something like addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); is good practice, it helps run code without getting null object references, same with Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, you can put all "destroy code" (removeListeners, nulling objects etc) there.
P.S. When using DisplayObject there no difference which version of Flash you are using, mechanism is the same for any after Player 9.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I understand that stuff, I am just wondering what percent of people have out of date flash players such as the original Player 9.